# Is there a word or phrase for the price for all units combined?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, money

Unit price * quantity equals what? For example if widgets have a $10 unit price, and a customer buys 3, then what is the $30 amount called? Total doesn't work since there could be other products purchased, as well as discounts or VAT calculations applied later.

Comment: The "value" of the carrots I bought was £2.45. But this will probably change with context. Please would you supply a sample sentence with a blank space for the word you need.

Comment: @WS2 Hi, thanks for reading my question. I don't have a sentence, I'm trying to give a programming variable a clear name to show what it represents. `unitPrice * quantity = $wordImLookingFor` would be the closest thing to a sentence.

Comment: Subtotal is a possibility.

Comment: Speaking as one who spent 40 years in the accountancy profession, I would head the column "value". Others may feel differently - but that would be my choice.

Answer (score 1):

In some settings, the established term for this amount is ***extended*** *price* or *extended cost*. The term is, however, unlikely to be readily understood by the general public, and it should thus be reserved for business-to-business communications in the fields in which it is an accepted part of the jargon.

Comment: I agree with it being accountant's jargon, but for the reasons you mention, I have always been disinclined to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The general word is [**subtotal**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subtotal):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> : the sum of part of a series of figures
>
> // Your *subtotal* is $14, and with tax, that will be $14.70.

Depending on context, a subtotal can represent the total of *each* product or the total of *all* products before tax and other calculations.

The site [NuORDER](https://helpdesk.nuorder.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005893046-Total-vs-Subtotal-Meaning) also mentions *subtotal*:

> This is the total price for *each* product in your order or the total price found for a selected delivery window in your order.

Again, note that context can change what *subtotal* refers to specifically.

However, they also use the term **item total** (in addition to both *subtotal* and *total amount*) in a screenshot of an example order summary:

[image: order summary that uses "item amount"]

Comment: Although, *item total* may, in fact, sometimes be used for this purpose, it can be confusing. Those who use that phrase, intend the word *item* in it to stand for a particular **type** (class, category) of the things they sell, while most people, in most contexts, understand the word to stand for a single thing (object, article, unit).